# internal error occurred while parsing heap dump

Tags: java, heap-dump

I've a heap dump file of size 6.89 GB. when i tried to open it in Eclipse mat analyzer, I'm getting an "internal error occurred while parsing heap dump".
I tried increasing the size of heap in MemoryAnalyzer.ini to 80% of the file size. Still no luck. I also tried using jhat and yourKit. Not helping. Someone kindly help me in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am little confuse on what you tried **increasing the size of heap in MemoryAnalyzer.ini to 80% of the file size**

**Solution 1:** I know you already tried but 80% is little confusing

1.open the MemoryAnalyzer.ini file ；

2.change the default -Xmx1024m to a larger size.

**Solution 2:**

If you have local setup of your code, add some debug points and take heap dumps at runtime on every debug break point (which will divide your big size heap dump file into smaller size file. You will solve size issue and it will be easy to get to root cause faster)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I read in some site that the size to be set in the memory analyzer.inf should be 80% of dump file to be read. That's what i meant. Anyhow that didn't work. Your second solution is a mind opener. i'll try and let you know.